# Custom role with no inherited permissions can see ROLE information in Snowsight App

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, roles

As the title says, we have many custom roles for Row Level Security Policies in a Reader account to allow them to be able to query objects and return a subset of the data.

The problem is that in the Snowsights app these roles can see all roles in my tenant, and the kicker is that they can go into the role details page and even get a list of users with these roles...

How can I remove the above access as this is information these roles should not be able to see.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this is a limitation on the Snowsight side where all the Roles are listed for any user with any roles irrespective of the RBAC model.
This is being worked on and the correct design to hide the roles and display only the relevant ones per user's role will be rolled out soon.

Comment: Thanks @Srinath, do you know if it is possible to hide the Snowsights Account tab by role or even in the main Snowflake UI to remove the ability to run show roles,  show grants of role <role> and show grants to role <role>?

Finally is there a timeline for the above works your mentioned?